# Calculating resultant force along vertical axis when using smartphone accelerometer

Tags: forces, kinematics, acceleration, rotation

I'm making an app which is using accelerometer to automatically detect damages on the route while driving. To estimate if damage occurred or not I'm using accelerometer (acceleration along vertical y axis) and some predefined thresholds. 
And here are two problems, first force of gravity - I was trying to use high pass filter (like described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-accel)) but results weren't satisfying, so I figured out as I'm estimating if damage occurred or not based on acceleration along y axes to always remove $9.81\, \mathrm{m/s}^2$ from values obtained from accelerometer along y-axis but here goes the second problem - rotation of device - and I'm not sure if my assumptions are correct:

1) Can I estimate the resultant vertical force based on acceleration obtained from accelerometer along 3 axes if I also know rotation angles of device around each axis (see picture) **if yes how to do it?**

[image]

2) Can I simply subtract $9.81\, \mathrm{m/s}^2$ from the resultant acceleration along vertical axis to eliminate force of gravity?

Comment: You can estimate the attitude of the phone relative to the z axis based on gravity and subtract that, but it's essentially like a high pass filter. If you have a precision rotation sensor, then you can use that information to update the estimate of direction of gravity, but even that will be unsatisfactory, I am afraid.

Comment: just to clarify - i know the attitude of the device based on magnetic field sensor and accelerometer sensor

Comment: The accelerometer can't give you the attitude and the magnetic field sensor can be off by 30 degrees. None of that really does much for you, either. The simple truth is this: the average sensory suit of a smartphone is not an inertial guidance system. I would probably keep looking at high pass filters of higher order or maybe a filter in the frequency domain.